# Issue with Sass syntax for @keyframes

Tags: css, sass

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to make this idea work, if it is even possible in Sass syntax. I've seen similiar things being used in SCSS syntax and I've tried multiple things to make it work. All of them failed for now.

This is the code, you can see what the idea behind it is from the code:

```css
@keyframes AdHop($from, $to)
  0%
    transform: scale($from)
  100%
    transform: scale($to)
```

So my question is; Is this even possible to do, if so, how?

Comment: You need to generate as much animations, as many pairs of `$from` `$to` values you have. So if one element animates from 0 to 100% and other is animated from -100% to 0, you need to have two `@keyframes` declarations.

Comment: I was hoping there was a DRY way for it :/ Still, thanks @3rdthemagical

Answer (score 0):

You can make a mixin

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/Pickra/pen/eyvJmx?editors=0100#)

```
@mixin adHop($from, $to, $name) {
    @keyframes #{$name} {
    0% { transform: scale($from); }
    100% { transform: scale($to); }
  }
}

@include adHop(1, 2, cool);
button:hover { animation: cool 1s; }
```